# Python 2 to 3 bytes/string error

Tags: python, string, byte

I'm trying to convert a Python library made for Python 2 to Python 3, [here is the code](https://gist.github.com/663175).

I have an error at line 152. In the Py2 version, the function is:

```
def write(self, data):
    self._write_buffer += data
```

The error is:

> TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes'
>   object to str implicitly

I found that I've to decode the variable, so I changed the function to:

```
def write(self, data):
    self._write_buffer += data.decode('utf8')
```

It works but I have another error in the asyncore library which said that

> (the Type) must be bytes or buffer, not
>   str

So, what can I do ?

Comment: So what's the problem exactly then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be clear about where you want bytes and where you want strings.  If you simply add `decode` and `encode` where the errors appear, you will be playing whack-a-mole.  In your case, you are writing a socket implementation.  Sockets deal with bytes, not strings.  So I would think your _write_buffer should be a bytes object, not a string as you now have it.

Line 91 should change to:

```
self._write_buffer = b''
```

Then you can work from there to ensure that you use bytes throughout.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That was the problem. I still have some errors but I'll try to correct my file to use bytes everywhere its needed.